# How to expose heroku app through domain

Tags: heroku

1. I have heroku app available at `https://myapp.herokuapp.com` (I am using SSL endpoint with self signed cert for now)
2. I have domain `mydomain.md` also available at `https://mydomain.md` - with signed cert.
3. I want to access my heroku app through this domain.

What I have to do to make it work? What I have to set on heroku and on my domain admin panel? I have never done anything with domains and I have no idea what is CNAME/APEX/ALIAS and I dont know what is the type of my domain.

---

I am trying to make it work... I added subdomain in admin panel: `api.mydomain.md`. 
And I did: `heroku domain:add api.mydomain.md`

1. And now I am confused - is it custom domain or it is root domain or what?
2. I have to add CNAME record in DNS records of `mydomain.md` or `api.mydomain.md`?
3. I tried to add CNAME record in both but it doesnt work...
4. What should be name of CNAME record - it must be 'www' or it may be anything?

when I type api.mydomain.md in browser it just shows 'under construction' page

Answer (score 0):

you need to point your domain to your heroku app.

here is a super simple documentation about that:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains

Answer (score 0):

The CNAME approached has never worked for me either, but this does...

1. Edit your domain's **DNS Zone File**
2. Create the following 3 A (host) records...

**First record...**

- Host = **@**
- Points To = **75.101.145.87**
- TTL = **whatever you wish (ex. 30 mins)**

**Second record...**

- Host = **@**
- Points To = **75.101.163.44**
- TTL = **whatever you wish (ex. 30 mins)**

**Third record...**

- Host = **@**
- Points To = **174.129.212.2**
- TTL = **whatever you wish (ex. 30 mins)**

In the end it should look something like [this screenshot](http://cl.ly/image/26200R082l0j). Hope this helps :)

Comment: But what are this IPs?

Comment: They are Heroku's IP addresses. You can access them in the browser directly to see so (though they will say "No such app"). Just add your domain in Heroku (which it sounds like you already did) and then create the records as I mentioned above and it'll work. It's how I have 8 Heroku apps running on custom domains...mine are root level, not subdomain, but it should be the same.